# ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException

Tags: weblogic12c

We have an application which we're trying to get to run on WebLogic 12.2.1.3.0 but even though we have the correct spring-aop-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar in the application's web-inf\lib directory we still get a

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException
```

I have tried adding `<prefer-application-packages>` for packagename org.springframework.* to the weblogic.xml and weblogic-application.xml and also setting `<prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>` but I cant' seem to get around this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You should add

```
<package-name>net.sf.cglib.*</package-name>
```

to
`<prefer-application-packages>` in your `weblogic-application.xml` to enable WebLogic to load cglib from your application classpath.